# What is the Rails Way (in 3.2.6) to respond to JSON with controller actions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a simple form in a Rails 3.2.6 application that has a select box. Based on the content in the select box on the change event, I'm submitting an Ajax request.

Then I have a .js.erb file that is rendered. But then I'm using that .js.erb file to render a partial.

Is that the Rails Way, or should I just skip the .js.erb file and render the partial from the controller action? It seems like an unnecessary step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have anything else in the `js.erb` file then I'd render the partial from the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I don't like generating / returning partials directly from controller and I would strongly suggest calling partial from appropriate `.js.erb` file - this way you will always know, what is returned after calling specific action, without looking at your controller. 
But I don't know, if this is a Rails way, it's just my common practice.